# How do I insert a column of strings into one field per unique identifier?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I attached screenshots if my text does not line up: [Undesired Results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK59p.jpg)

I have a table with a client_id and multiple rows of medications. I want to insert all medications per client into a single comma delimited field.

My table looks like this:

```
===================
|Client__ID|DESC   |
|==========|=======|
|500011    |Plavix |
|----------|-------|
|500011    |Zocor  |
|----------|-------|
|500011    |aspirin|
|----------|-------|
|500006    |aspirin|
|----------|-------|
|500006    |Plavix |
|----------|-------|
|500006    |Zocor  |
|----------|-------|
===================
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
========================================
|Client__ID|DESC   |MEDS_COMB           |
|==========|=======|====================|
|500011    |aspirin|Plavix,Zocor,aspirin|
|----------|-------|--------------------|
|500006    |aspirin|Plavix,Zocor,aspirin|
|----------|-------|--------------------|
========================================
```

My actual results look like this:

```
========================================
|Client__ID|DESC   |MEDS_COMB           |
|==========|=======|====================|
|500011    |aspirin|NULL                |
|----------|-------|--------------------|
|500006    |aspirin|NULL                |
|----------|-------|--------------------|
========================================
```

This is the query I've written so far:

```
SELECT [CLIENT_ID]
 , [DESC]
 , (STUFF((SELECT CAST(',' + [DESC] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
FROM [AZCLMED]
WHERE (CLIENT_ID = [AZCLMED].CLIENT_ID) AND END_DATE IS NULL
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS MEDS_COMB
FROM [AZCLMED]
ORDER BY [CLIENT_ID] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `XML PATH('')` is off, which is part of your problem.

I also didn't understand what you want to do with the `[Desc]` column.

Getting the results you want is as easy as this:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Client__ID INT, [Desc] VARCHAR(55));
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (500011, 'Plavix');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (500011, 'Zocor');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (500011, 'Aspirin');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (500006, 'Aspirin');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (500006, 'Plavix');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (500006, 'Zocor');

SELECT 
     [CLIENT__ID]
    ,MIN([DESC])
    ,SUBSTRING(
        (
        SELECT ',' + [Desc]
        FROM @TABLE T2
        WHERE T2.Client__ID = T1.Client__ID
        ORDER BY [Desc]
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,2,100) AS MEDS_COMB
FROM @TABLE T1
GROUP BY T1.Client__ID
;
```

However, I feel a bit uncertain about the `MIN([DESC])` selection, since it seems arbitrary.  If there is some logic behind the choice of this value for this column, please share it with me; I didn't see it in your original query.

Comment: The table and results that I posted was just an example of the data. There are 100,000 records in my actual table. Your query worked great. How can I apply that to a much larger table?

Comment: The query should run the same on any table with the selected columns. Everything from`SUBSTRING(` to `MEDS_COMB` is what should interest you most, it seems.

Comment: Is there some special logic to how you want to rows formulated? As I said, the `MIN()` seems a bit arbitrary to me.  If you want me to give a more detailed answer than I already have, I'm going to need a bit more information about actual data that you have / want.

Comment: @Chris, you said, " Your query worked great". Could you please then accept this answer and not walk away with the answer? StackOverflow works when people show each other appreciation for their time and effort. Thanks